# Graphics.clear() not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I am having alot of trouble getting Graphics.clear() working properly.

It is not clearing the whole control, it does the following:

[image]

Here is my UserControl class:

```
public partial class Screen : UserControl
{
    Graphics sg;
    public Screen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sg = this.CreateGraphics();
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
    public void drawPixel(int x, int y,Color c)
    {
        sg.DrawRectangle(new Pen(c,1),x,y,1,1);
    }
    public void clear()
    {
        sg.Clear(Color.Black);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is an entirely normal mishap when you store a Graphics object.  Always the wrong thing to do.  Its clipping area is based on size of the control when you created it.  Can't work correctly when the size changes.  You must do this correctly by overriding the OnPaint() method instead, use the passed e.Graphics object.  You probably should use an Bitmap object to implement drawPixel().  Difficult to make this performant enough, add an updateImage() method that calls this.Invalidate() so the bitmap on the screen gets redrawn.  Still leaves you with the same problem though.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is not going to be as easy as java graphics.

Comment: It sounds harder than it is; but using `CreateGraphics` got you started on the wrong foot. Also note: The `Graphics` object does not __contain__ any graphics; it is a **tool** that lets you draw onto a related bitmap, including a control's surface. -  For more detailed advice we simply do not know enough about what you are trying to achieve..